# Get child of next consecutive div

Tags: jquery

Apologies for the noobness of the question, I've done a search but can't find anything matching 'get child of next consecutive div'.

Any ideas please?

```
//get current
var current = $('#holder').find('img.current');
//get next image
var next = 

<div id="holder">

<div class="item odd">
    <img class="current" src="project_1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="item even">
    <img src="project_2.jpg">
</div>
<div class="item odd">
    <img src="project_1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="item even">
    <img src="project_2.jpg">
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the same container `#holder`, this solution is less dom-dependent:

```
var current = $('#holder').find('img.current');
var next = $("#holder img").eq(current.index("#holder img") + 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/j4yS6/

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  The less dom-dependent gets the points

Answer (score 2):

```
var current = $('#holder').find('img.current');
var next = current.parent().next().find('img');
```

Read the documentation on [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).